# OnClick on element populate an array with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So, I have different elements like this:

```
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="45" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="46" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="46" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="47" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
```

For each click on element, I put the id of the element and some other informations in an array.

```
var arr = [];

$('[data-action="change_status"]').click(function(event) {
    $(this).data('status', 'newValue');

    arr.push({
        current_status: $(this).data('status'),
        current_date: $(this).data('date'),
        current_roomid: $(this).data('roomid')
    });
});
```

My problem is if the user click two times on the same element, it creates two rows in this array.

How can I check that an id already exists into the array and how can I update it with the last clicked value ?

Finally, I would like to pass this array in Ajax to a PHP page.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried with `inArray` ?

Comment: you can disable each parameter after a click.

Comment: You could avoid the problem by simply putting a class on the elements to be used in the array, but only actually create the array at the point it's going to be used - in your case when the AJAX request is sent.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily do this using your `roomid` and `Array.prototype.find`

> [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) loops over the array and checks if any value is found. If so it returns the array item.

If you click change status it will say `undefined` the first time and the array entry the second and after.

```js
var arr = [];

$('[data-action="change_status"]').click(function(event) {
    $(this).data('status', 'newValue');

    const arrElement = arr.find( (element) => {
      return element.current_roomid == $(this).data('roomid')
    });
    if (isInArray == undefined)
    {
      
      arr.push({
          current_status: $(this).data('status'),
          current_date: $(this).data('date'),
          current_roomid: $(this).data('roomid')
      });
    }
    else
    {
      //update
      arrElement["current_status"] = $(this).data('status');
      arrElement["current_date"] = $(this).data('date');
      arrElement["current_roomid"] = $(this).data('roomid');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="45" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="46" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="46" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="47" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
```

I however would suggest are more SQL-type approach here. Since you have `roomid`, why not make it the `primary key`. With this method we can skip a lot of code.

```js
var roomObject = {};

$('[data-action="change_status"]').click(function(event) {
    $(this).data('status', 'newValue');
    const roomId = $(this).data('roomid');
    const dateValue = $(this).data('date');
    const statusValue = $(this).data('status');
    roomObject[roomId] = { current_status: statusValue,
                    current_date: dateValue,
                    current_roomid: roomId};
    //of course roomId is a little redundant now, but let's keep it there.
    console.log(roomObject);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="45" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="46" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="46" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="47" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try next stuff:

```
if (arr.filter(e => e.current_roomid === $(this).data('roomid')).length === 0) {
  arr.push({
     current_status: $(this).data('status'),
     current_date: $(this).data('date'),
     current_roomid: $(this).data('roomid')
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler. Gather the data when you submit

```js
$('[data-action="change_status"]').on("click", function(event) {
  $(this).data('status', 'newValue');
  $(this).text('newValue');
  $(this).toggleClass("newValue")
});

$("#send").on("click", function() {

  let changes = [];
  $('[data-status]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data("status") === "newValue") changes.push({
      "id": $(this).data("roomid"),
      "date": $(this).data("date")
    })
  })
  console.log(changes)
});
```

```css
.newValue {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="45" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-02" data-roomid="46" data-status="Open">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="46" data-status="Close">Change status</div>
<div data-action="change_status" data-date="2019-03-03" data-roomid="47" data-status="Open">Change status</div>

<button type="button" id="send">Send</button>
```